# knockoutjs - debug with circular reference in view model

Tags: knockout.js

The view model has a circular reference, by design, making the use of `<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data)"></pre>` for debugging to throw:

```
Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON;
Bindings value: text: ko.toJSON($data)
```

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 9):

It is ultimately the call to `JSON.stringify` inside of `ko.toJSON` that causes your error.

One way that you can control the output of your JSON is by supplying a `toJSON` function on your object as described here: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/controlling-how-object-is-converted-to.html.  That way you can remove the circular reference in the appropriate place.

There are a few other techniques that you could use for this as well.

- You can pass a second argument to `ko.toJSON`.  This is the `replacer` option to `JSON.stringify` as described here:

  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify.

  For example, you can pass an array of properties to include like:

  ```
  ko.toJSON(myobject, ["one", "two", "three"])
  ```
- You can attach a property that you don't want to get turned into JSON as a "sub"-observable like:

  ```
  this.data = ko.observable();
  this.data.parent = parent;
  ```

In this case, `data` will get turned into `JSON`, but `parent` will just disappear, as it is a property on an observable that already gets unwrapped into its value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to add a reference to Dojo (may be just for debugging), then dojox.json.ref.toJson seems to be able to serialize JSON objects with circular references.

In this case, you can do:

```
<pre data-bind="text: dojox.json.ref.toJson($data)"></pre>
```

also there is this library worth checking that could probably provide a more lightweight solution than dojo: http://mixu.net/snapshot/