# Avoid error of cyclic value in view, knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

My knockout model (version 3.3.0 of knockout) is something like this:

```
var Node=   function(id,name,parentNode) {
            var self = this;
            self.id= ko.observable(id);
            //more here...
            self.nodes = ko.observableArray([]);
            self.parentNode = parentNode;
        }
```

When this model is bound to a view, knockout throws an error in the console (non-breaking error):

> TypeError: cyclic object value
>
> ...m http://www.json.org/json2.js");return
>   E.stringify(a.a.c(b),c,g)},zc:function(c...
>
> knockout-3.3.0.js (line 20, col 344)

So, I assume somewhere internally, knockout calls a JSON.stringify method.
By combining the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13204337/knockoutjs-debug-with-circular-reference-in-view-model) and [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knockoutjs/wn52WeqvR1Q), I concluded that if I add a "toJSON" method in my model, where I exclude the "parentNode" property, the error will disappear. And so it has.

My toJSON function:

```
self.toJSON = function(){
                    return {
                        id: self.id(),
                        name: self.name(),
                        //exclude parentNode
                        nodes: ko.toJSON(self.nodes())
                    };
                }
```

So my question: is there a more efficient way to write this function to be more generic? I want to include all (unknown) properties, excluding a few (known) ones.

Calling ko.toJSON on the model and then deleting the property as the first link suggests won't work, because of the cyclic reference. So any other alternatives?

**EDIT:** The implied call toJSON when binding is made by another ko plugin, but it really could be anything. I've setup an isolated fiddle to demonstrate both the problem, and my temporary solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/zq09znLa/1/

Comment: check the working sample here http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/24754/ . let me know cheers

Comment: @supercool Sorry, but your answer isn't related to my problem. See my edit, I have added a reproducible fiddle.

Comment: Register nodes in a dictionary by id, then store nodes as an array of ids, with a computed to generate the actual node list. Similarly, store parent node id and have a computed (if you want) to get the node itself.

Comment: The fiddle in your example doesn't work (at least not in Chrome), KoLite isn't loaded because server response MIME type is not set (from raw.github.com)

Comment: @Tyblitz the fiddle isn't supposed to work: see the console error and the fiddle comments. If you comment out the respective parts, it will work. Tested on chrome also.

Comment: In any case, it has nothing to do with the KoLite plugin because it is not being loaded: chrome says `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CodeSeven/KoLite/master/knockout.dirtyFlag.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`, meaning `The implied call toJSON when binding is made by another ko plugin,` simply doesn't happen in the fiddle. Also don't get how the reference could ever be 'cyclic'..  How can a param passed to the function be equal to `this` ??

Comment: To recap: yes Chrome complains about the plugin, (Firefox doesn't). It doesn't matter. All the plugin does is trigger an implied ko.toJSON call on the model. The error is due to that. The model has a reference to parentNode, and the cyclic reference is due to that. Try to think how you would serialize the model and you will understand what the cyclic reference is.

Comment: @RoyJ thanks for the suggestion, but refactoring isn't an option now. Will keep it in mind for future implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the replacer function (see [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461037/knockout-serialization-with-ko-tojson-how-to-ignore-properties-that-are-null)) to exclude unwanted keys:

```
var excludeKeys = {
    parentNode: true
};
```

It's a little awkward, as you have to temporarily remove self.toJSON to avoid infinite recursion.

```
self.toJSON = function () {
    var save = self.toJSON;
    delete self.toJSON;
    var result = ko.toJSON(self, function (key, value) {
        if (key in excludeKeys) return null;
        return value;
    });
    self.toJSON = save;
    return result;
};
```

I've updated your fiddle so it runs in Chrome and demonstrates the solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/zq09znLa/4/

**Update**: I've made a version with toJSON defined as an empty function in the prototype. It makes the program run successfully (in terms of having expected output) by just nullifying the serialization.

```
Node.prototype = {
    toJSON: function () {}
};
```

I wanted to make a prototype-residing `toJSON` that works, but the fiddle isn't testing whether the toJSON is doing the right things.

http://jsfiddle.net/2o7cnzL2/1/

Comment: That part with the temporal removal of "toJSON" was brilliant. Thanks!

Comment: @pkExec JSFiddle's TidyUp had messed up the HTML, so that's fixed. Plus, new solution using prototype instead of local `toJSON`

Comment: No, your latest edit in the fiddle that nullifies serialization is not what was asked. Better keep it as before (minus the HTML errors) for future readers.

Comment: Agreed that it doesn't do what was asked. I thought it was useful to point out that the fiddle doesn't test whether the serialization is actually being done correctly.